# Send array in angularjs put mehod

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, xmlhttprequest

as per api request i must send data  `categories: [1,2,3,4]`

I have tried

```
data: {
      categories: [1,2,3,4]
}
```

But it gets sent as

```
categories[]:1
categories[]:2
categories[]:3
```

Not as `ategories: [1,2,3,4]`

How can i send an array of numbers in angularjs $http method

`categories: [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Why you say it gets sent as `categories[]:1
categories[]:2
categories[]:3` and not as `[1,2,3,4]`? Are you checking it in the backend service and it is arriving like this?

Comment: How are you sending it? How are you testing it? Please provide more information.

Comment: @lealceldeiro when inspecting chrome network tab, i see the Form Data

Comment: the way it gets send now, it should arriving in backend as array, if you want it to be as a string just `'[' + [1,2,3,4].join(',') + ']'`

Comment: Look at [this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/MLwnpyvHUcn9nYZydM1h?p=preview) it doesn't seems to be a problem to send an array in a `PUT`

Comment: @faw, Chrome network tab shows it like that but it should arrive as an array to the endpoint (backend service). Please, check it in the service you are calliing. For instance if you're using Java, you could set a breakpoint.

Comment: Have you stringify your data before hitting http

Comment: @lealceldeiro there is no problem with it, i even get a 201(success) message but the server do not save them properly.
I have answered my question and link to why it did not worked

Answer (score 1):

Finally i have found the answer to my question after alot of research 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3121

I should have sent it as `"categories[]": [1,2,3,4]`

not as categories = [1,2,3]